# Ontario Speeding: Does filing an appeal for a conviction by HTA Reg 340/94 (30km/h over) automatically grant an immediate stay of license suspension?

Tags: traffic, ontario, process, speeding, stay-order

My sister, really unfortunately got her first speeding ticket. 30km/h over as a G2 Driver and we had no idea how severe of a matter this was.

She lost the ticket and decided she was going to pay it and so waited for the conviction to be mailed to her. She was unaware and never told that the speeding ticket comes with [a mandatory license suspension](https://www.ontario.ca/laws/regulation/940340#:%7E:text=(a)%20upon%20a%20novice%20driver%E2%80%99s%20first%20conviction%20for%20any%20of%20the%20offences%2C%20suspend%20the%20driver%E2%80%99s%20licence%20of%20the%20person%20for%2030%20days%3B) for novice drivers and has been only given a few days warning of this, 0 of which are business days. Which really feels pretty draconian to me. In any case, she requires her car to get to work and there are no feasible public transit options for her.

I am wondering if she files a notice of appeal then will that automatically grant an immediate stay of license suspension? [The Region of York Appeal process document](https://www.york.ca/resource/appeal-process-guide-i-and-ii) seems to suggest that just filing an appeal might automatically grant a stay of license suspension in certain situations but doesn't list when this is the case or if the stay is immediate.

I've been on google for a couple of hours now and am really struggling to get information on this. Any information or pointing in the direction of information would be greatly appreciated. I imagine this info is in an act somewhere but I can't seem to find it so any suggestions there would be greatly appreciated.

We are planning on speaking to a lawyer but given that she just got notice of this on Friday by mail that won't be possible until after her suspension has begun on Tuesday.